# Collectstatic on same folder?

Tags: django

am planning to move my project to production ! so hosted on pythonanywhere. Now am just confused about how to deal with collectstatic

```
This is my folders:

project
   -app1
   -app2
   -static   // this contains all the static files for both app1 and app2
   -utils
```

So, as i have 100% of all static files inside static, where to perform collectstatic? Can i perform collectstatic inside "static" folder itself ?

or do i need to point out seprate folder like "staticfiles" inside project ? My overall question is can we do collectstatic without pointing it to seprate folder ?

Comment: You don't point it to anywhere. When you execute `manage.py collectstatic` it collects everything it could found using `STATICFILES_FINDERS` and copies them into `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: yes so where the STATIC_ROOT should be pointed to ? as of now i have like this ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/staticfiles')``` but am asking can that be like ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static')``` (As there is a folder static already presented !

Comment: It doesn't even have to be under your `project` folder. Static assets are meant to be served by a web server (apache, nginx, etc), not Django itself. So anywhere that is readable by the web server user (such as `www-data`) is fine.

Comment: yes i understand that, let me make it clear ! I already have all static files under "static" ! So now i do ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/staticfiles')``` it will copy all files from static to staticfiles right ? Now i would be having two folders with same files ! So is it possible to collect static on same folder ?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the `staticfiles` folder. Your app specific static assets (or a project specific one, such as your `project/static` folder) are considered part of the source code and, for example, committed to the SCM tool (e.g. `git`). You execute `collectstatic` during deployment to let the web server find those files. It is normal to have two copies of the same files in some cases, but in general the deployed assets don't have to be on the same server, or even under a filesystem folder (e.g. S3 deployments).

Comment: okay, as you said i tried with ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/staticfiles')``` and did collectstatic but now everything become not found with error 404 :(

Comment: That's a different question. You may post your new config and the error mesasage (with full traceback, if available) as a new question.

Comment: okay got it repaired ! Now its working :) thank you @Selcuk

Comment: I agree with @Selcuk . I also don't like this, when django creates two copies of the same files. that is not okay, because:
1) When I update the file in one folder, I should run collectstatic to update it on another folder
2) it creates two copies of all the static files. Some hosting providers count every file and therefore let's assume you have 500 files and run collectstatic, you will have  1000 files, which sometimes reaches to the files limit of the hosting provider.

Comment: @Saidmamad That's how Django works. Yes, you should run collectstatic. You should also migrate your database when making changes. Deployment is not a trivial process. That's why we have a thing called devops.